# Присваивание в дескрипторах

Tags: python, ооп, дескрипторы

```
class IntegerValue:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if type(value) != int:
            raise ValueError('возможны только целочисленные значения')
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
class CellInteger:
    def __init__(self, start_value = 0):
        self.value = IntegerValue()
        self.value = start_value
```

Вопрос в следующем, когда я объявляю дескриптор в `__init__`, то `value` не присваивается дескриптор, а присваивается значение, хотя по идее переприсваивания происходить не должно. Но, когда я присваиваю `value` дескриптор в самом классе `value = IntegerValue()`, то `self.value = start_value` отрабатывает как дескриптор.

Comment: Всё так, дескриптор должен быть именно в классе, а не в отдельном объекте